# Python Selenium web driver with chrome driver gets detected

Tags: python, selenium

I assumed that the chrome browsing session opened by Selenium would be the same as the google chrome local installation. But when I try to search on this website, even just open it with selenium and manually control the search process, I will get an error message where as the search result returns fine when I use regular chrome with my own profile or in incognito window. 
Whenever I search on this issue, I find results stating mouse movements or clicking pattern gives it away. But it is not the case as I tried manually control after opening the browser. Something in the html request gives it away. Is there anyway to overcome that? 
The website in question is: https://www.avnet.com/wps/portal/us

The error message when in automated session. 
 [image]

Comment: This question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33225947/can-a-website-detect-when-you-are-using-selenium-with-chromedriver).

Comment: I did try that. Unfortunately it did not help. I edited the $cdc away from my chrome driver. I guess a better way to ask is: is there any other difference between a regular chrome and chrome webdriver?

Comment: "browsing section" - did you mean "browsing _session_"?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley fixed, Thanks

Comment: @JeffC Just like IddoE posted. Any selenium broswer get can reproduced the issue    browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
browser.get('https://www.avnet.com/wps/portal/us')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the the website in question https://www.avnet.com/wps/portal/us I am not sure about the exact issue you are facing perhaps your code block would have given us some more leads whats wrong happening. However I am am able to access the mentioned `url` just fine :

Code Block :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.avnet.com/wps/portal/us')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
```

Console Output :

```
Page Title is : Avnet: Quality Electronic Components & Services
```

Snapshot :

[image: Avnet: Quality Electronic Components & Services]

---

### Update

I had a relook at the issue you are facing. I have read the entire *HTML DOM* and have found no traces of **Bot Detection** mechanisms. Had there been any **Bot Detection** mechanisms implemented the website even wouldn't have allowed you to traverse/scrape the [**DOM Tree**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) even to find the **Search Box** even.

Further debugging the issue the following are my observations :

- Through your *Automated Script* you can proceed till sending the searchtext to the *Search Box* successfully.

[image: searchbox]

- While manually you search for a valid product, the auto-suggestions are displayed through a `<span>` tag as the html below and you can click on any of the auto-suggestions to browse to the specific product.
- Auto Suggestions :

[image: span-yes-parts]

- SPAN tag HTML :

```html
<span id="auto-suggest-parts-dspl">
                                                                
                                                                
                                                                <p class="heading">Recommended Parts</p>
                                                                <dl class="suggestion">
                                                                                <div id="list_1" onmouseover="hoverColor(this)" onmouseout="hoverColorOut(this)" class="">
                     <div class="autosuggestBox">
                      <a href="/shop/us/products/aimtec/am8tw-4805dz-3074457345627076774/?categoryId=&amp;fromPage=autoSuggest" rel="nofollow" id="autosuggest_1" class="autosuggest_link" onkeydown="scrollDown(event,this)">AM8TW-4805DZ</a>
                      <p class="desc1">Aimtec</p>
                      <p class="desc2">Module DC-DC 2-OUT 5V/-5V 0.8A/-0.8A 8W 9-Pin DIP Tube</p>
                     </div>
                                                                                </div>
```

- This `<span>` is basically not getting triggered/generated when we are using the *WebDriver*.

[image: spanTagNotTraggered]

- In absence of the *Auto Suggestions* if you force a search that results into the error page.

### Conclusion

The main issue seems to be either with the **form-control** class or with the function **scrollDown(event,this)** associated with **onkeydown** event.

Comment: u can reproduce by sending keys to `#searchInput` and ENTER, as @echo wrote in the question

Comment: You are close, just type in the search bar and you can reproduce the issue

Comment: @echo Check out my answer update and let me know your thoughts about it.

Comment: @DebanjanB Thanks, I am a little confused still as what need to be done to trigger the Auto Suggestions? Do I need a mouse movement in the Webdriver?

Comment: The peculiar things is that it would not show up even if I manually input and click.

Comment: @echo Yes, that is the point I tried to explain in my answer along with the relevant `<span>` tag

Answer (score 3):

#TooLongForComment

To reproduce this issue

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Default')
options.add_argument('--incognito')
options.add_argument('--disable-plugins-discovery')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', chrome_options=options)
browser.get('https://www.avnet.com/wps/portal/us')

try:
    search_box_id = 'searchInput'
    myElem = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, search_box_id)))
    elem = browser.find_element_by_id(search_box_id)
    sleep(randint(1, 5))
    s = 'CA51-SM'
    for c in s:  # randomize key pressing
        elem.send_keys(c)
        sleep(randint(1, 3))
    elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
except TimeoutException as e:
    pass
finally:
    browser.close()
```

[image: reproduced]

I've used `hexedit` to edit `chromedriver` key from $cdc_ to fff..

[image: hexedit]

- Investigate how it's done by reading every JavaScript block, look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39441582/2655092) for detection example
- Try to add extension to modify headers and mask under Googlebot by changing user-agent & referrer `options.add_extension('/path-to-modify-header-extension')`

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly where I am at. I tried use hexedit (I used HxD Hex Editor) but with no avail

Comment: either investigate how it's done by reading each JS block which is a lot of work way above this answer's scope and might not help if they have server side ML classification or add extension to modify headers and mask under googlebot, give that a try & update